# Can a function name be changed at execution time?

Tags: javascript, function

I've a function named `cleanProduct` that call several other function such as `cleanProductBrand` or `cleanProductTitle`. These functions are inside an object called `adv`.

When testing this javascript code:

```
// Setup code
var adv = {};
adv.cleanProductBrand = function()
{
    // do stuff
};
adv.cleanProductTitle = function()
{
    // do stuff
};

adv.cleanProduct = function()
{
    adv.cleanProductBrand();
    // ...
    try
    {
        adv.cleanProductTitle();
    }
    catch( e )
    {
        // Send debug to my server with the properties of adv.
        var properties = [];
        for ( var prop in adv )
        {
            properties.push ( prop );
        }
        adv.reportError( e.message, properties.join( ',' ) );
    }
};
// Executed code
adv.cleanProduct();
```

Most of the time, everything works perfectly fine, the `catch` is never executed.
But when looking at the error messages that I send to my server, I see that this error is appearing several times. (note the lack of capitalised 'T' in title)

```
TypeError: adv.cleanProducttitle is not a function
// Followed by all the properties listed in the reportError
```

And more importantly, the properties of `adv` are all correct.

The user agent is somewhat inconstant but most of the time, it's happening on windows.

Of course, the first thing I tried is to find if `cleanProducttitle` exists directly in the code, this is not the case.

So the question is: Is it possible that some browsers change arbirtary the name of a function at execution time, and if yes, how can I catch it and still execute my code properly?

Comment: Since you don't have similar issue with cleanProductBrand(), I bet there is still a call of cleanProducttitle() somewhere.

Comment: "change arbirtary the name of a function at execution time" --- it's not possible.

Comment: This is the only place where cleanProductTitle / cleanProducttitle (in this case) is called, plus the errorMessage corresponds to the one I send in this very `try/catch`.